Assignment problem using scipy optimize linprog to solve in Python
I am running into an error when trying to run my code for this Assignment Cost minimization problem in Python and was hoping someone could illuminate me on what I have done incorrectly here.
The question:

My code:
import numpy as np
import time

n = 10   # n: number of jobs/workers
cost = np.random.rand(n,n)   # generate an n-by-n random matrix

from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = cost.reshape((n**2,1))   # reshape the cost matrix to a column vector

#row constraints (sum of each row equals 1)
A_eq_rows = np.ones((n, n**2))
b_eq_rows = np.ones(n)

#column constraints (sum of each column equals 1)
A_eq_cols = np.zeros((n, n**2))
for i in range(n):
    A_eq_cols[i, i::n] = 1
b_eq_cols = np.ones(n)

#solve for A_eq and 
A_eq=np.vstack((A_eq_rows, A_eq_cols))
b_eq=np.hstack((b_eq_rows, b_eq_cols))

start_time = time.time()   # start timing

res = linprog(c, None, None, A_eq, b_eq)

end_time = time.time()   # end timing
elapsed_LP = end_time - start_time

print("Minimum cost = ", res.fun)
print("Elapsed time = ", elapsed_LP)

I keep getting my Minimum Cost as None and am not entirely sure what I've done wrong with this. I have a decent fundamental understanding of how to resolve this problem but have limited experience in doing this through Python.
I know that it has n^2 variables and 2n-1 linearly independent constraints. Therefore, a BFS of the assignment problem has 2n-1 basic variables, and for each assignments, exactly n of the n2 variables are nonzero so every BFS is degenerate. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: I am aware I can solve this through the function scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment() and have done this but wanted to compare my answer by running this problem as a linear program.

(1) Always look at res.message (2) Your matrix representation is incorrect. Do a 2x2 problem first (write down all scalar constraints and form the matrix by hand.)

Could you elaborate on this? I understand that given n jobs and n workers, we would like to assign each job to one worker, and each worker to one job. If job j is assigned
to one worker i, the cost of the assignment is cij (cost matrix). Xij = 1 if job j is assigned to worker i and Xij = 0 if job j is NOT assigned to worker i. From what I understand this is just a transportation problem where all the supplies and demands are ones and zeros. I'm not entirely sure how to set up this 2x2 problem along with its constraints in python.

The constraints for a 2x2 problems are x11+x12=1, x21+x22=1, x11+x21=1,x12+x22=1. Form the LP matrix (4x4) from the coefficients. Each row and each column should have 2 nonzeros. Write this matrix out on a piece of paper. Your A_eq_rows has 4 nonzeroes for each row, which is obviously wrong.

Thanks that was helpful. I have my matrix written out correctly I'm just not sure how to make my code reflect this for A_eq_rows

Consider n=3. The LP matrix should look like
x00 x01 x02 x10 x11 x12 x20 x21 x22
 1   1   1
             1   1   1   
                         1   1   1 
 1           1           1
     1           1           1
          1          1           1

As with all network models, the number of nonzeros in each column is 2.
It can be difficult to populate the A matrix, but in this case there is an easy structure:
import numpy as np
n = 3  # n: number of jobs/workers
cost = np.random.rand(n,n)   # generate an n-by-n random matrix
from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = cost.reshape((n**2,1))   # reshape the cost matrix to a column vector   


# allocate LP matrix
A = np.zeros((2*n,n*n))

# sum_j x[i,j] = 1 for i=0..,n-1
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        A[i,n*i+j] = 1.0   # same column mapping as reshape 

# sum_i x[i,j] = 1 for j=0..,n-1
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        A[n+j,n*i+j] = 1.0  # same column mapping as reshape

# rhs
b = np.ones(2*n)

res = linprog(c, None, None, A, b)
print(res.message)
print("Minimum cost = ", res.fun)

# print assignment
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (abs(res.x[n*i+j])>0.0001):
            print(f'{i}->{j} with cost {cost[i,j]}')
 

Indeed the A matrix looks like:
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])

The matrix interface is a bit primitive and can be difficult to use. A much easier way is to use a modeling tool like PuLP (that automates the mapping of decision variables to LP columns).

This will not scale particularly well. Both linprog and milp accept sparse matrices directly.

It scales nicely as we only touch the nonzero elements of A. A is sparse.

In memory, right? A does not need to be carried as a dense representation.

Even if we weren't talking about memory and were talking about runtime instead, you have nested for loops where I expect a vectorised implementation to be more efficient.

When generating random test data, always set a seed for reproducibility.
There is no need to loop over i. You can form the sparse constraint matrix directly.
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.optimize import linprog

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
n = 10
c = rand.random((n, n))

eye = sp.eye_array(n)
A = sp.vstack((
    # sum over i must equal one (kronecker)
    sp.kron(np.ones(n), eye),
    # sum over j must equal one (kronecker)
    sp.kron(eye, np.ones(n)),
))

result = linprog(c=c.ravel(), A_eq=A, b_eq=np.ones(2*n))
assert result.success, result.message
x = result.x.reshape((n, n)).astype(int)
print(c.round(2))
print(x)

[[0.64 0.27 0.04 0.02 0.81 0.91 0.61 0.73 0.54 0.94]
 [0.82 0.   0.86 0.03 0.73 0.18 0.86 0.54 0.3  0.42]
 [0.03 0.12 0.67 0.65 0.62 0.38 1.   0.98 0.69 0.65]
 [0.69 0.39 0.14 0.72 0.53 0.31 0.49 0.89 0.93 0.36]
 [0.57 0.32 0.59 0.34 0.39 0.89 0.23 0.62 0.08 0.83]
 [0.79 0.24 0.88 0.06 0.34 0.15 0.45 0.8  0.23 0.05]
 [0.4  0.2  0.09 0.58 0.3  0.67 0.2  0.94 0.37 0.11]
 [0.63 0.93 0.44 0.95 0.5  0.43 0.62 1.   0.95 0.46]
 [0.76 0.5  0.53 0.79 0.41 0.73 0.71 0.93 0.11 0.73]
 [0.93 0.97 0.01 0.86 0.98 0.96 0.15 0.97 0.89 0.82]]
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]

